# Set field foreign key value directly in the view Django

Tags: python, django, view

I have a model named record but it requires a foreign key (barcode)  and I don't want to add it in the form with a select (the way that django does it by default) instead of that I want to insert it manually , so I did this in the **forms.py**

```
class add_record_form(forms.ModelForm):
    barcode = forms.CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = Record
        exclude = ('product',)
```

But I don't know how to pass the value to my view and add it to the record table. I get the error "Record.barcode has to be an instance of barcode"

And when I got the barcode instance then I had to add the product associated to that barcode in the view , that's why I have excluded the product field in the form.

**views.py**

```
def add_barcode_view(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        formu = add_record_form(request.POST)
        if formu.is_valid():
            bcode = formu.cleaned_data['barcode']
            prod = Producto.objects.get(barcode=bcode)
            cant = formu.cleaned_data['amount']
            aux =  prod.amount - cant
            add = formu.save(commit = False)
            if (aux >= 0):
                prod.amount= aux
                prod.save()
                add.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/record/%s' %add.id)
            else:
                formu = add_record_form(instance = add)
                mensaje = "amount not available"
                ctx = {'men':mensaje, 'form': formu}
                return render_to_response('inventario/add_record.html', ctx, context_instance = RequestContext(request))

    else:
        formu = add_record_form()
        ctx = {'form': formu}
        return render_to_response('inventario/add_record.html', ctx , context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

**Record Model and Barcode** 
I want to insert the code of a barcode manually in the add record form

```
class Barcode(models.Model):
    code            = models.CharField(max_length=13, unique = True)
    date            = models.DateField(auto_now = True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.code

class Record(models.Model):
    barcode         = models.ForeignKey(Barcode)
    record_date     = models.DateField(auto_now = True)
    producto        = models.ForeignKey(Producto)
    amount          = models.IntegerField()
    description     = models.TextField(max_length=150)
```

**Traceback**

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/add/record/

Django Version: 1.5.3
Python Version: 2.7.9
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.admindocs',
 'sif.apps.home',
 'sif.apps.inventario',
 'sif.apps.web_services.ws_producto',
 'rest_framework')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "D:\MIS DOCUMENTOS\Documents\GitHub\proyecto_formativo\sif\sif\apps\inventario\views.py" in add_record_view
  156.      if formu.is_valid():
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in is_valid
  126.         return self.is_bound and not bool(self.errors)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in _get_errors
  117.             self.full_clean()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in full_clean
  274.         self._post_clean()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py" in _post_clean
  315.         self.instance = construct_instance(self, self.instance, opts.fields, opts.exclude)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py" in construct_instance
  52.             f.save_form_data(instance, cleaned_data[f.name])
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py" in save_form_data
  466.         setattr(instance, self.name, data)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py" in __set__
  405.                                  self.field.name, self.field.rel.to._meta.object_name))

Exception Type: ValueError at /add/record/
Exception Value: Cannot assign "u'144253491444'": "Record.barcode" must be a "Barcode" instance.
```

Comment: Please show us full stacktrace and your `Record` model!

Comment: @ozgur Sorry , It's better now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your naming is not correct. Please follow [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) rules and use English words for variables, class names, everything. Please change `formu` to `form`, `Producto` to `Product` and `add_record_form` to either `AddRecordForm` or `RecordForm`.

The problem is you are doing a database lookup with a string instead of an actual `Barcode` object. Another problem is that, you didn't specify how to get the right `Product` instance before creating the record so I'll create a product whenever a new barcode is created.

You should update your view function as follows:

```
def add_barcode_view(request):
    ...
    if formu.is_valid():
        barcode, created = Barcode.objects.get_or_create(
            code=formu.cleaned_data['barcode']
        )
        add = formu.save(commit=False)
        add.barcode = barcode

        prod, created = Producto.objects.get_or_create(barcode=barcode)
        add.producto = prod 
        ...
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply code will look like:

```
    if form.is_valid():
        record = form.save(commit=False)
        record.barcode = barcode
        record.save()
```

form's `save` method with `commiit=False` won't trigger `save` on your model object, that way you can retrieve ready to save object, assign some values to it's fields or change something and save it after that.

Of course in above example, barcode should be `Barcode` instance.

Comment: you mean something like this?
Because I'm still getting error 
bcode = formu.cleaned_data['barcode']
record.barcode = Barcode.objects.get(code=bcode)
record.save()

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `clean` in the `add_record_form` to avoid error like the following:

```
def clean(self):
        barcode = Barcode.objects.get(id=self.cleaned_data.get("barcode"))
        return {'barcode': barcode}
```